# Django - Postgresql - JSON Field - #>> operator - Index of out range

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

In a **django** project which is using **postgresql** DB, there is a collection called **'table1'** which has a **JSON field** called **'data'**. In this JSON field, we will be storing an email against a dynamic key. For ex:

```
ID | DATA
1  | '{"0_email": "user1@mail.com"}'
2  | '{"3_email": "user2@mail.com"}'
3  | '{"1_email": "user3@mail.com"}'
```

Problem Statement:

> Filter out the rows in which "user2@mail.com" exists in the "data" field.

My Approach:

```py
from django.db import connection

@transaction.atomic
def run(given_email):
    with connection.cursor() as crsr:
        crsr.execute(
            """
            DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT id, data
            FROM table1
            WHERE
                data #>> '{}' like '%\"%s\"%'
            """,
            [given_email]
        )
        while True:
            crsr.execute("FETCH 10 FROM mycursor")
            chunk = crsr.fetchall()
            # DO SOME OPERATIONS...
```

Explanation for `data #>> '{}' like '%\"%s\"%'`:

1. I am using the `#>>` operator to get object at specific path of JSON **as text**.
2. I am providing `'{}'` empty path so that I will get the **complete JSON as a text**.
3. From this stringified JSON, I am checking if the given_email (user2@mail.com from the above example) is present

Then, I have pointed this function to a API in django in which I will get the `given_email` in payload. I am facing the below error which triggering this function:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/debug_cursor.py",
> line 49, in execute
> return utils.CursorWrapper.execute(self, sql, params)   File "project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 67, in execute   File
> "project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers   File
> "project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 87, in _execute
> self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction() IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/debug_cursor.py",
> line 54, in execute
> raw_sql = raw_sql[:truncate] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Observations:

1. I don't think there is anything wrong with the query. In fact, I have tried this query in DBeaver and I am getting the expected response.
2. I am suspecting that the `'{}'` part in the query is causing some issue. So, I have tried to replace it with `'\\{\\}'`, `'{{}}'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, `'{}'` is interpreted as a `text` whereas a json path is of type `text[]`.
So you should cast it as `text[]` in your query : `WHERE data #>> '{}' :: text[] like '%\"%s\"%'`

Then `data #>> '{}' :: text[]` could be simplified as `data :: text` which will provide the same result.

Finally, you convert your json data into a text and then you use the pattern matching `like` operator. This solution may provide some unexpected results with some values which contains the expected email as a substring but which are not equal to that expected email.

In order to have the exact result for the expected email, you should use a jsonb function, for example :

```
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(data :: jsonb, ('$.* ? (@ == "' || expected_email || '")') :: jsonpath)
```